# Vue2 how to use $refs to target an element and remove css class

Tags: html, css, vue.js, dom, vuejs2

I want to remove the css class of an element when a method is called.
but I want to do this using $refs.

template:

```
  <div class="modal"  ref="myModal"></div>
```

method:

```js
      closeDropdown: function() {
            this.$refs.myModal.$el.removeClass("open");
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
this.$refs.myModal.classList.remove("open");
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. `const modalElement = this.$refs.myModal; // reference to the DOM element`
2. `modalElement.classList.toggle("custom"); // use classList API of DOM element`

`classList` API reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList, you can use this API to modify its classes using the add(), remove(), replace(), and toggle() methods.

You can also refer to this CodeSandbox Vuejs example: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-wood-s3nhq?file=/src/App.vue:269-481